# Origin of कराग्रे वसते लक्ष्मीः (karaagre vasate lakshmi)

Tags: identification-request, shloka

One of the most popular and widely used Shloka in Hinduism is

> कराग्रे वसते लक्ष्मीः करमध्ये सरस्वती ।
>
> करमूले तु गोविन्दः प्रभाते करदर्शनम् ॥
>
> karAgre vasate lakShmIH kara-madhye sarasvatI |
>
> kara-moole tu govindaH prabhAte kara-darshanam ||

**Meaning**: At the **Top** of the Hand (i.e. Palm) Dwell Devi Lakshmi and at the **Middle** of the Hand Dwell Devi Saraswati,
 At the **Base** of the Hand Dwell Sri Govinda; Therefore one should Look at one's Hands in the Early Morning and contemplate on Them.

It seems like **[another](http://blog.practicalsanskrit.com/2009/07/force-is-in-your-hands.html)** version with small modification also exist.

> कराग्रे वसते लक्ष्मीः करमध्ये सरस्वती ।
>
> करमूले स्थिता गौरी मंगलं करदर्शनम् ॥
>
> karAgre vasate lakShmIH, kara-madhye saraswatI |
>
> kara-moole sthitA gaurI, mangalaM kara-darshanam ||

The difference is instead of Lord Govinda, the second version mentions about Gauri at the base of the Hand.

Which Hindu scripture has the mention of the above shloka and which version is mentioned out of the above two?

Comment: Nice question. It is one of the first shlok we utter in morning 1

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Correct, it is one of the most common. To be honest, I could not found its origin doing Google. Only the expert who has read many scriptures could tell if it is part of which scripture, I guess.

Comment: Digital Corpus of Sanskrit didn't give any positive results. http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=fundstellen&IDWord=104125

Comment: We used to have this shloka in a pushtaka(book) called "Vandana" in primary school time.

Answer (score 12):

The sloka is originally from the **Vishnu Purana**.However,the version given in that Purana differs slightly from those given in the question.

The Vishnu Purana version states:

[image]

> Karaagre Vasate Lakshmih Karamadhye Saraswati ||Karamule Stitho
>   Brahma Prabhate Karadarsanam||
>
> On the top of the palms resides Lakshmi,in the middle Saraswati and at
>   the base of the palms resides Brahma.Hence,one should always see the
>   palms at early morning.

Quoting from the book [Dharma Bindu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf)(the essence of all Dharma Shastras):

> Vishnu Purana defined Brahma Muhurta: Raatrena paschima yaamaasya
>   muhurto yastrutiyakah, sa Brahmaa iti vigneyo vihitah sa prabodhane/
>   Pancha pancha Ushahkaalah saptapancha arunodayah, ashta pancha bhavet
>   praatastah Suryodayah smritah/ (Considering that Brahama Muhurta is
>   from 4.08 am to 4.56 am and Ushodaya or Sunrise is at 5.44 am. **The
>   first view that a person on opening eyes is the right palm saying:
>   Karaagre vasate Lakshmi karamadhye Sarasvati, Karamule sthito Brahma
>   prabaate karadarshanam/ ( Lakshmi on to of the palm fingers, Sarasvati
>   in the middle of the palm and Brahma at the bottom of the palm**

[image]

Comment: Is there a a possibility that it's referring to Brahman rather than the four-headed gods Brahma?  Because both are written as brahma in Sanskrit.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan No .I think its Lord Brahmaa only(not Brahman).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan BTW there is Brahma Tirtha at the base of the thumbs& at the middle of the palm  there is Agni Tirtha .,but as per this sloka Saraswati resides there.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan ब्रह्मा (brahmā) is four headed Brahma. ब्रह्म(brahma) is Supreme Brahman. Verse says ब्रह्मा

Comment: Where does this shloka occur in Vishu Purana? Can you give exact reference?

Comment: No I can't give.. It is mentioned in that book (Dharma Bindu) that it's from the Vishnu Purana. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan this is certainly the 4-headed ब्रह्मन्. Note the preceding स्थितः (स्थितो because of विसर्ग​ सन्धि) which indicates that ब्रह्मन् is used in the masculine gender which refers to the creator. The para-ब्रह्मन् is in neuter always and the स्थितः would have been a स्थितम् in that case.

Comment: Agni is abhimani for vak devatha. even saraswathi is also primary abhimani of vak if saraswathi is there then agni should be there..@Rickross, if you know the tartamya you would have got this..

Comment: I do know about Saraswati's connection with Agni .. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27524/4732) @PrasannaR