# which mantra(s) should be chanted before going to sleep and awake from morning?

Tags: mantras, tradition

I heard that some of our ancestors chanted mantras (a few lines) before going to bed and when wake up in the morning. When they wake up in the morning, they first look at their palms and chant something,

I don't know which mantra and the reason from where they followed in our Hinduism.

Could you please provide some explanation on the above one.

Comment: You can see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/why-it-is-considered-good-to-see-ones-own-palms-after-waking-up-in-the-morning/21829#21829) for one of the mantras .. It is to be chanted as soon as we wake up in the morning upon seeing the palms

Comment: I saw your answers and mantras. **The [Nitya Karma PujA PrakAsh] Book (on pp 19) mentions the following sloka:** however the link couldn't able to redirect.

Comment: Yes thanks for letting me know, that link is now broken ..I will give u an alternate link of the book in a moment

Comment: Here is another link for the same book: http://www.dwarkadheeshvastu.com/001-Epics-PDF/Nitya-Karm-Pooja-Prakash/Nitya-Karm-Pooja-Prakash.pdf

Comment: @Rickross thanks so much.Very good book.

Comment: @Rickross: My bad time I don't know the language in this book. Do you have in any of these in english version.

Comment: @ssr1012 Yes, the language of translation is Hindi and the slokas are in Sanskrit.. what is ur mother tongue? the book is from the Gita Press, Im not sure whether they have it in any other languages or not

Comment: @Rickross: Thanks we will check in _Gita Press_. BTW Telugu, Tamil & English can be ok for me.

Comment: The morning I am aware of. Because I also used to chant during my childhood. It starts like "कराग्रे वसते लक्ष्मी:..."

Comment: @ssr1012 Ok but u already know the mantra from my answer .. u can see the transliteration and u'll know how to pronounce it

Comment: @Rickross thanks I will do it

Answer (score 4):

Chant Maha Mrityunjaya Mantra before going to the bed and thanks to you God for a beautiful day. In morning try to do Surya Namaskar and Chant [Surya Namaskar Mantra](https://yogachapter.com/surya-namaskar-sun-salutation-benefits-and-steps/). It will give you both physical and spiritual benefits.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE. Answers on this site should be detailed enough to solve the questioner's doubts and also should be backed up by proofs from Hindu scriptures like Vedas, Puranas, Upanishads, etc. So, please edit your answer to provide more details and proof from scriptures in order to make it more reliable.

Comment: I am very wonder on your answer, doing and chanting surya namaskar at the time the person awake from bed? _**(Note I am doing the surya namaskar occasionally in the physical fitness center when time is permits)**_

Answer (score 4):

The Mantra to be recited before sleeping is:

> **Rāmaskandam Hanumantam** 
>   **Vainatēyam Vṛkodaram** 
>   **Śayane Yah-Smareṇ-Nityam** 
>   **Duh-Svapnam Tasya Naśyati** 
>    
>   If one remembers Rama, Skanda, Hanuman, Garuda and Bhima daily before sleeping, one’s bad dreams shall be destroyed.

This Sloka calls upon all the powerful entities to wipe out all the bad dreams, and give us a good sleep.

The Mantra to be recited after waking up is:

> **Karāgre Vasate Lakśmi** 
>   **Karamadhye Sarasvati** 
>   **Karamūle Sthitē Gauri** 
>   **Prabhāta Kara Darśanam** 
>    
>   In the tip of my palms resides Lakshmi, in the middle, Sarasvati, and on the bottom, Gauri. Hence, I take Darshana of them in my palms every morning!
>
> - Alternative versions are **Govinda** or **Brahma** instead of **Gauri** in the third line

This Mantra invokes the three goddesses Gauri, Lakshmi and Sarasvati to bestow auspiciousness upon one every morning.

Comment: Ramam Skandam Hanumantam

Comment: Morning one I follow from childhood. But I was not aware of the first one (during bed time). thanks for sharing