# Scriptural reference to say Lord Vishnu and Parvati devi are same

Tags: vishnu, puranas, gods, parvati

I want to know if there is any scriptural reference i.e a small event that shows Narayana and Parvati are same.

The reason for my initial belief that they are same is the following:

1. All gods are various forms of parabrahma swaroopa so we cannot attribute gender.
2. Both Narayana and Parvati devi are alanakara priyas
3. Both have similar motto i.e protection of dharma by taking avataras

Comment: Read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13998/3500).

Comment: @The Destroyer Thanks for the link. Answer looks great. I would like to keep this open to see if anyone writes another answer from a different perspective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[In the Brahmanda Purana](http://www.astrojyoti.com/brahmandapurana-4.htm), we have the Lalitopakhayana section. And there we find Goddess Lalita Tripurasundari creating the entire creation from scratch. Every deities were also created from her during the process.

So, during that time, Lord Vishnu and Goddess Parvati both came from Goddess Lalita's right eye which is of the nature of Sun. So, this is an indication that Tattva-wise they are same or that they have similarities.

> She is of the form of these 16 Nityaa Devis. Maha Shambhunatha praised
>   Her in many ways. Order of Creation. She extended Herself in both male
>   and female forms and continued the process of creation.
>
> A. From the left eye, which was of the nature of Soma (moon) came
>   Brahma and Lakshmi Devi.
>
> B. **From the right eye, which was of the nature of Soorya (sun) came
>   Vishnu and Parvati.**
>
> C. From the third eye, which was of the nature of Agni (fire), came
>   Rudra and Sarasvati.

Also, note that Lord Vishnu and Goddess Parvati are [also mentioned in scriptures as brother and sister.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26748/which-scripture-says-parvati-is-vishnus-sister) .

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This also shows triplet of siblings Vishnu, pravati and Brahma, Lakshmi devi and Shiva, Saraswati.

Comment: Yes there are other scriptures too that mention Vishnu-Parvati as brother sister.. I have written an answer on that too.. @Tej

Comment: Any English translation of lalita upakhyana?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi See my message in the Agama room.

Comment: by the above statements this means Rudra,Saraswati, is higher in order than bhrama, laskhmi, Vishnu and Parvathi... But Saraswathi is wife of Brahma, she should be less than or equal how??  Rudra and saraswati from Agni  means Rudra is also abhimani of Vak (how is that possible, Rudra is manas abhimani along Chandra) See @Rickross if you puranas specify order means you should be candid establish without any conflict in other scripture, in case of conflict with multiple scripture that statements should be ignored

Comment: How is higher lower order established? Also where is the contradiction? @PrasannaR

Answer (score 0):

In, the Kurma Purana, Bhagavati Parvati while Granting boons to Sri Krishna, tells him that There's no difference between the two of them.

> Kurma Purana, Purva bhaga, Chapter 25

[image]